# How should I install a dimmer switch that calls for neutral-to-hot connections?

Tags: electrical, led, light, dimmer-switch, neutral

I have 6 dimmable spotlights and there was previously a normal one way switch to turn them on and off. I bought a dimmer switch and in the installation instruction it's saying that I have to put live in dimmer and neutral switch to live (L1).

I got two switches opposite, one for the main light and second for spotlights. All neutrals are together, only lives are separated.

How am I supposed to connect the dimmer switch correctly? Because when I connect it as the instruction says, it's blowing the fuse on the whole ground floor. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the wallbox please?

Comment: Do you have a manufacturer and model number for the new dimmer?  I'd like to check installation instructions

Comment: Did you photograph the old switch before you took the wires out?